# How to bevel a right-angle edge?

Tags: bevel

I'm trying to make this tv frame beveled but I don't know how to make it with proper topology.  How can I fix this?  Thanks

This is the area:

[image]

As you can see, the bevel effect doesn't align in the corner properly and creates all these folding and overlapping vertices:

[image]

I've attached the .blend

[image]

Comment: according to your images, by blender's term that's not exactly beveling. It's more like you are trying to subdivide. Also when I look at your file I see some of the corners have been subdivided, you certainly can't apply modifiers on such inconsistency. Try model them back to right angle and apply subdivide modifiers.

Comment: @SVAFnemesis sorry for the late reply...It turns out there was a weird issue with the vertices in the example I posted.  All other corners of the tv frame beveled nicely.  Basically I had to join each edge of the bevel (in this case 7 vertices) with the corner.  It definitely did not look like beveling in the example I posted though, I agree.  Hope that makes sense